# Summing together values from the same table in different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table on each database for a region of a company with the number of sales per month like so:

```
Region1.dbo.SalesPerMonth          Region2.dbo.SalesPerMonth

ID     Month     Sales             ID     Month     Sales
1      Jan          23             1      Jan          21
2      Feb          19             2      Feb          15
3      Jan          31             3      Jan          25
...    ...         ...             ...    ...         ...
```

I am looking to write a query to join these tables into one table that shows the sales for the entire company per month, so it has the total sales from all regions added together:

```
AllRegions

ID     Month     Sales
1      Jan          44
2      Feb          34 
3      Jan          56
...    ...         ...
```

I am however new to SQL and am not sure how to go about doing so. Any help or advice on how to write the query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `JOIN` tables by `ID`, `SUM(Sales)` and `GROUP BY Month`

Comment: Are these database on the same server? Coz a simple join will not work if they're not on the same DB server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union together the two tables, and then aggregate by `ID` and `Month` to generate the sum of sales.

```
SELECT
    ID, Month, SUM(Sales) AS Sales
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Month, Sales
    FROM Region1.dbo.SalesPerMonth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Month, Sales
    FROM Region2.dbo.SalesPerMonth
) t
GROUP BY
    ID, Month
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
SELECT *
FROM Region1.dbo.SalesPerMonth
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Region2.dbo.SalesPerMonth
)
SELECT [id]
      ,[Month]
      ,SUM(Sales) AS Sales
FROM DataSource 
GROUP BY [id]
      ,[Month]
```